# Stream sound to loudspeakers on windows

Tags: winapi, audio

What do I need to know to stream a sound of a given frequency (that is, generated programatically at runtime, not a file) to the loudspeakers of the system on MS Windows?

Please be as specific as you can, I have an idea of winAPI, but I'm more of a linux programmer, so function names are welcome.

The answer with the most concrete steps and functions to call will be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function you need to use is "waveOutOpen". You can follow examples in MSDN that use this function or google for some example in the Internet that uses this function. Take a look, for example, at

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3